# Find mean of subset based on string in R

Tags: r, stringr, grepl

I have two columns I am working with, 'Grade' (chr) & 'HomeOwnershipStatus' (chr).  I want to find what percentage of (HomeOwershipStatus == 'RENT') have a Grade of 'A'.

I would first need to subset HomeOwnershipStatus so that it only includes 'RENT' rows and then find the mean of that subset with a grade of 'A'.  I could do this by subsetting but I am trying to do this in one line.

My thought process was mean(d$HomeOwnershipStatus == 'RENT'[grepl('A',d$Grade)]) but it only return NA.  Any direction would help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`mean(d$HomeOwnershipStatus == 'RENT'[grepl('A',d$Grade)])` is a good try, but order-of-operations is the issue. `'RENT'[grepl('A',d$Grade)]` will take higher precedence than `==`, attempting to subset the string `'RENT'`.

Without seeing your data, I also can't tell if `grepl` is needed at all. If you want to see when grades are `'A'`, you should use `== 'A'` just like you used `== 'RENT'` to see the rentals. However, if the grades are strings like `"A", "A+", "A-"`, then you do indeed want `grepl` to find any grade that include the letter `"A"`. I'll continue using `grepl`, but you can switch to `==` if `grepl` isn't needed.

I'd do this:

```
mean(grepl('A', d[d$HomeOwnershipStatus == "RENT", "Grade"]))
# same thing, alternate way to write:
mean(grepl('A', d$Grade[d$HomeOwnershipStatus == "RENT"]))
```

Option 1 is a standard `data[rows, column(s)]` index -- you want the "Grade" column from the rows where `HomeOwnershipStatus == "RENT"`.

Option 2 is `vector[index]`-- our vector is `df$Grade`, the indexes we want are when `HomeOwnershipStatus == "RENT"`.

Comment: This was a great help thank you!  I did need to use grepl because the Grade had multiple variations of grade A.  Thanks again.